# What's the lambda expression to check to see if one property in any of a group of objects matches any of a group of strings?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of objects myObjects which each have a "Status" property. I have a list of strings myStrings. I want a conditional that evaluates if any members of myObjects have statuses that match any of the members in myStrings. I feel like there should be a linq method/lambda expression that evaluates this, but I'm not as familiar with them as I hope to be. I was trying something like this:

```
(myObjects.Any(x =>
            x.Status.Equals(myStrings.Any(x.Status))
```

Any help you guys and gals have would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myObjects.Any(x => myStrings.Contains(x.Status))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + `Any`:

```
bool anyIntersection = myObjects.Select(x => x.Status).Intersect(myStrings).Any();
```

Comment: +1, more simple would be `myObjects.Any(x => myStrings.Contains(x.Status))` but this is more efficient in terms of performance

Comment: @IlyaIvanov, you sure, `Any.Contains` can simply short-circuit. Intersect requires at least one full pass... Haven't measured, but I'd suspect that Contains is faster.

Comment: @jessehouwing what we are talking about? Best case, expected case or worst case scenarios?

Comment: @jessehouwing: `Intersect.Any` is also short-circuiting since `Intersect` is using deferred execution, `Any` executes it and stops at the first match.

Comment: If we are indeed talking about premature optimization, then don't forget that `Intersect` caches second parameter on first iteration, so it would be better to pass shorter sequence there. You can always check **.NET** [sources for Intersect here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#ae06318d1f5fb355#references)